# python trying to insert accentueted letters into openldap

Tags: debian, python, openldap

I'm trying to insert users in OpenLDAP using python. The problem is, when user has accentuated letters such as ç, é, è, python does not react well and insert values OpenLDAP encodes to base64:

Here is my python code for edition (same problem with insertion, but easier here):

```
def edit(self, uid, item, value):
    mod_attrs = [ (ldap.MOD_REPLACE, item, value) ]
    try:
        LDAPEntry.connect(self).modify_s('uid='+uid+','+USER_BASE_DN, mod_attrs)
    except ldap.LDAPError, e:
        print e
```

When I insert print value, I get, for instance:

```
François Dujardin
```

and in the LDAP, with ldapsearch, I get:

```
cn:: U3TFzJFkISD1kdfv1eQ==
```

Whereas using ldif file and ldapadd -f my_file.ldif gives me the appropriate result.

I think there is a problem with my script encoding, which does not give to OpenLDAP data in its appropriate format. But I don't know how to solve it. I have tried:

```
value = value.decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-8')
```

or

```
value = value.decode('unicode_escape').encode('iso-8859-1')
```

and get different base64 encoded values, but not the appropriate one :/

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you have your internal representation right. `uid` should be a valid unicode string. Second, you should check which encoding your ldap server is expecting. utf-8, iso-8859-1, iso-8859-15, win1252, ... Besides that, if `value` is already a unicode string, you don't need any decode afterwards.